# Find the number of diagonals

Tags: javascript, node.js

> ### Number of diagonals
>
> N Given a natural number. Your task is to find the number of diagonals of a convex polygon with N sides.
>
> Incoming information:
>
> The unique number in the INPUT.TXT input file, N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10^9)N ( 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^9) is entered.
>
> Outgoing data:
>
> In the output file OUTPUT.TXT print a unique number, the answer to the problem.
>
> ```
>   i.txt   o.txt
>      5       5 
>      6       9
> ```

My code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = fs.readFileSync('input.txt', 'utf8');

const [n] = data.split(' ').map(item => parseInt(item));
fs.writeFileSync('output.txt', `${Math.floor(n*(n-3)*1/2)}`, 'utf8');
```

Number of diagonals Wrong answer (test 16)  js  147ms   1396KB

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript represents numbers using IEEE-754 double-precision (64 bit) format. It can give you full precision up to 2^53 - 1(~9x10^15) for integers but your answer can be larger than that. You should look into [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) for your purpose.